# How do I configure the Puppet agent without an FQDN or domain for the Puppet master?

Tags: puppet

I am foraying into the world of puppet and got my hands on [Pro Puppet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430260408). I used Vagrant to fire up two instances of the [puphpet-debian75-x64](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puphpet/boxes/debian75-x64). I named one of them puppetagent and the other puppetmaster. Once setup i ran

- `apt-get install puppet facter` on puppetagent
- `apt-get install puppet puppetmaster facter` on puppetmaster.

(In puppetmaster instance )The next step was to edit the `puppet.conf` file in `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` and add `certname = <FQDN of host>` under [master]. I was a little confused here as I did not have a FQDN and instead just typed in puppetmaster after which I tried to restart my puppetmaster with `invoke-rc.d puppetmaster start` which gave this `[FAIL] Starting puppet master failed!`

I am really confused at this step. Since I am just testing, how do I get a domain name? And do i have to create an another instance via vagrant to act as host? Any help with this step will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you get when you run it in `no-daemonzie` mode? `sudo puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize`

Answer (score 2):

you can skip the requirement for DNS by setting up your /etc/hosts file.  For example on your puppetmaster and agent you will need an entry like the following:

```
192.168.0.1   puppet.example.com    puppet
192.168.0.2   agent.example.com     agent
```

the example.com is completely arbitrary.  After you have this configured you can proceed with generating your certs on the puppetmaster which should generate successfully. The important thing is to have your puppetmaster entered as puppet as this is how the agent will find it by default.